# Can you have cascading report parameters from a dropdown to a textbox?

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, cascadingdropdown

I have a SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services report with three parameters I'd like to implement some kind of dependency relationship between.

- The first parameter is DateRange
  which is a drop down with various
  numbers of days back to make a date
  range from the present day. It will have a "Custom" value which will be used to flag when the Start and End DateTime parameters should be used instead.
- The second and third would be
  datetime parameters where the user
  enters some kind of valid DateTime
  string representation or clicks the
  Calendar box and selects that way, ie "02/20/2009"

The problem I have is that all the material I've stumbled across on dependent parameters shows cascading relationships where there is a drop down based on a query determining the next drop down.

**How can you cascade from a dropdown, that uses a query, to a non-queried DateTime Textbox?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the answer you are looking for, but I solved this (and other) problems by embedding the report into a web page (using the ReportViewer control). I use AJAX to cascade values across dropdowns in ways that would be exceedingly difficult in Reporting Services, and then pass the parameters to the reports in the codebehind.

I've found this to be much easier, as I'm not constrained with how I create my input controls. YMMV, though.

Answer (score 0):

Set the default value to an expression. I believe, be default any default values that start with an equals sign forces the report to treat current parameter as dependent on all parameters above the current parameter.